# can not find neither my.cnf nor init.d files in /etc directory

Tags: mysql, configuration-files

I want to configure the my.cnf option file. mysqld --verbose --help gave this output

```
    Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
    /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

However, I can not find the file in either of those places. Does MySQL start looking for a default options first? Should I create my.cnf file manually then? Also there is no init.d file at all, how that can be possible? Everyone seems to find it in /etc directory, but I don't have it there.

Comment: It may depend on operating system. For example on my install in RHEL 5 my.cnf was on `/usr/my.cnf` Anyway you can try to look it with simple find, i.e. `find . -name "my.cnf"`

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I did look for it using mdfind, it gave a huge list of my.cnf files, but I am not sure if MySQL server is actually referring to those files, because they are not in the places where they should actually be.